# SQL Statement to return before a certain character

Tags: sql, string, sql-server-2008

I need to be able to output a string which will return everthing up a specified character, I believe making use of `charindex` is the best way to approach this but I am unsure of the syntax required.

**Some examples:**

- If a string is equal to `"601-Test-Test2_Test3"` then I wish to return `601`
- If a string is equal to `"42-Test_test3"` then I wish to return `42`
- If a string is equal to `"1-Test_test3"` then I wish to return `1`

Comment: What database system? Different systems have different functions for string manipulation.

Comment: Take a look at substring & charindex functions

Comment: This is clearly a home work assignment.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647/split-string-in-sql

Answer (score 1):

```
-- this should do what you require:

DECLARE @string nvarchar(50)

SET @string = '601-Test-Test2_Test3'

SELECT @string as 'test string', left(@string, charindex('-', @string) - 1) AS 'Upto-'
```